# No module named django.core

Tags: python, django

I'm following the step by step guide [here](http://jeffbaier.com/articles/installing-django-on-an-ubuntu-linux-server/) and I hit an error at the "Create Django Project" step when I try the command;

> django-admin.py startproject myproject

The error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/usr/local/bin/django-admin.py",
>   line 2, in 
>       from django.core import management ImportError: No module named
>   django.core

Running on Ubuntu Server with Python 2.6.

I'm sure it's a really simple error, and something do with Python paths, but I'm a Linux newbie. Thanks!

Comment: What is the output of the `python -c` command on that page, and what do you get when you `ls` that directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Daniel Roseman's comment, I investigated and found my symlink was broken. Just had to recreate that and it worked nicely.